# Let the limits of the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively be $k$ and $k^3.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I came across the following problem which is as follows:

> Let the limits of the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively be $k$ and $k^3.$ If the sequence $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...........$ has a limit,then the value of this limit is which of the following:
>   $1.0$ or $1$ or $-1$
>   $2.0$ or $1$
>   $3.k+k^3$
>   $4.k^4.$

Can someone point me in the right direction?Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: A sequence and it's subsequence have the same limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if the sequence given by $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...........$ has a limit it implies that all of its converging subsequence must have the same limit.

This implies $a_1,a_2,a_3,...........$ will have the same limit (as this sequence is convergent) as the above sequence and also
$b_1,b_2,b_3,...........$ must also have the same limit (as this sequence is also convergent) as this sequence.

This forces the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...........$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,...........$ to have the same limit

Implying $k^3=k$

Solving this we get the possible values as $0,1,-1$

This implies that the sequences $a_1,a_2,a_3,...........$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,...........$ converges to either $0$ or $1$ or $-1$. So the original sequence must also converge to either of the above values(If it converges at all).

Comment: Actually, if a sequence has a limit than *all* subsequences have the same limit; no necessity to make a restriction about *converging* subsequences.